# How to detach an IAM role into AWS running instance and attach a new IAM role into that particular instance using java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am creating an Amazon EC2 instance with a specific IAM Role.

Now I want to detach that IAM role and attach a new IAM Role or replace with a new IAM Role. I am finding the options to do with CLI but I am not able to find any option when the instance is running through java code.

Here is my code:

```
RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest().withImageId(imageID)
        .withBlockDeviceMappings(blockDeviceMappings).withInstanceType(type).withMinCount(1).withMaxCount(1)
                .withIamInstanceProfile(new IamInstanceProfileSpecification().withName(iamRole))
                .withUserData(getUserDataScript())
                .withNetworkInterfaces(new InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification().withAssociatePublicIpAddress(true)
                        .withDeviceIndex(0).withSubnetId(subnetID).withGroups(groups));
        RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = ec2Client.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify... Are you wanting to _change_ the IAM Role attached to an existing EC2 instance, or are you wanting to specify an IAM Role when _launching_ a new EC2 instance?

Comment: I want to change IAM role attached to an existing aws instance which has already some IAM role

Comment: It would be great if I could do based on the instance-id of the running instance

Comment: And you wish to do this via Java (not the console or CLI), is that correct?

Comment: Yes because rest everything is working with java  and if it is available in console that means there must be a way to do via Java code also , just I am not able to find that api

Answer (score 0):

To change the IAM Role associate with an Amazon EC2 instance, first disassociate the existing one:

[disassociateIamInstanceProfile()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#disassociateIamInstanceProfile-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.DisassociateIamInstanceProfileRequest-)

The, attach a new one:

[associateIamInstanceProfile()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#associateIamInstanceProfile-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AssociateIamInstanceProfileRequest-)

Comment: Thanks,I will be trying it tomorrow